# Create mac application without window

Tags: macos, cocoa

Hi want to create an application like xscope or pixelruler, but all application that i have created have a stardard windows.
how can i draw directly in a screen whitout windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't draw without a window, but you can have a window with a transparent background.

[This tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html) should help you out. You'll want a custom `NSWindow` subclass, and to make it transparent you pass in `NSBorderlessWindowMask` for the `styleMask`. Then you can do your drawing in your window's content view.